# Parse date without timezone to local timezone

Tags: kotlin, java-time, zoneddatetime, localdatetime

I have date without Z because it always in UTC. I want to parse it into LocalDateTime with local time and vice versa

For example:

local timezone UTC+1 
server date "2020-01-31 04:38:00" in UTC 
formatted will be "2020-01-31 05:38:00"

and vice versa 
local time "2020-01-31 05:38:00" in UTC+1 
formatted time will be "2020-01-31 04:38:00"

I tried this

```
            val formatter = DateTimeFormatter
                .ofPattern(Type.API.formatter)
                .withZone(localTimeZone)

            LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter).toString()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse your input as `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2020-01-31 04:38:00".replace( " " , "T" ) ) ;
```

You claim to know for sure that the string represents a moment as seen in UTC, that is, with an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

If you want to adjust into a time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

I do not know why you involved `Locale`. The `Locale` class has nothing to do with date-time values. A `Locale` is only needed if you are localizing when generating text to represent your date-time value, to determine names of month or day-of-week, and issues of capitalization, punctuation, abbreviation, order of parts.

```
Locale locale = Locale.JAPAN ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/KSwx0K).

Both `odt` & `zdt` represent the same moment, the same simultaneous point on the timeline, but differ in their wall-clock time. People in Tunisia set their clocks one hour ahead of UTC. So in `zdt` we see the time-of-day as 5:38 rather than 4:38.

```
ldt.toString() = 2020-01-31T04:38
odt.toString() = 2020-01-31T04:38Z
zdt.toString() = 2020-01-31T05:38+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
output = 2020年1月31日金曜日 5時38分00秒 中央ヨーロッパ標準時
```

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing you, I mean local time. Fixed it